# Erro no calculo de uma PA com Haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

A função não retorna o resultado esperado mas segui a formula e não consigo entender o erro na logica. Espero retornar o i-ésimo termo.

```
termoPA :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 

termoPA p1 r i | i == 0 = 0
               | otherwise = p1 + r * termoPA p1 r (i-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fórmula do [Termo Geral da PA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica) ou n-ésimo termo é dada por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde:

- *a1* é o primeiro termo da PA.
- *r* é a razão da PA.
- *n* é o índice do n-ésimo termo da PA..

Usando a formula corréta:

```
termoPA :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
termoPA a1 r n | n == 0 = 0
               | otherwise = a1 + (n -1) * r
```

Exemplo:

Dada uma PA `(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, …)` onde o primeiro termo é 1 a razão é 3 o 7º termo será:

```
main = print(termoPA 1 3 7)
> 19
```

Teste o exemplo no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/AnnualSparklingTranslations

O algorítimo recursivo, que considero contraproducente pois o algorítimo anterior oferece o mesmo resultado em uma única passagem e esse precisa de n-passagens para obter o mesmo, constitui em incrementar `p1` em `r` enquanto decrementamos `n`, retornando `p1` quando `n == 1`:

```
termoPA :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 

termoPA p1 r n | n == 0 = 0
               | n == 1 = p1
               | otherwise = termoPA (p1 + r) r (n-1)
```

Utilizando a mesmo PA do exemplo anterior:

```
main = print(termoPA 1 3 6)
>16
```

Teste aqui no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/RotatingGenerousRedundantcode

Comment: PS: Caso tenha duvidas sobre minha afirmação do segundo algorítimo ser contraproducente teste em ambos os algorítimos  `termoPA 1 3 99999999999999999`.